# create html table with json response

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have the json response which I want to make it as a table .I want to get the sum of week1,week2,week3,week4 for specific month on specific meetinghash
[image: Required table]

I need to calculate the monthly total for 4 weeks and append create the table as in image.
I have I have tried as

```js
const data = [
    {
        "UserName": "Sarathy Devaraju",
        "week": "Week 1",
        "MeetingHash": "Hold/Uncategorized",
        "monthinwords": "May",
        "count": 2
    },
     {
        "UserName": "Sarathy Devaraju",
        "week": "Week 2",
        "MeetingHash": "Hold/Uncategorized",
        "monthinwords": "May",
        "count": 3
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Sarathy Devaraju",
        "week": "Week 2",
        "MeetingHash": "1st Presentation / Meeting",
        "monthinwords": "Jun",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Sarathy Devaraju",
        "week": "Week 1",
        "MeetingHash": "Follow-On Meetings",
        "monthinwords": "Jun",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Sarathy Devaraju",
        "week": "Week 2",
        "MeetingHash": "1st Presentation / Meeting",
        "monthinwords": "May",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Sarathy Devaraju",
        "week": "Week 3",
        "MeetingHash": "Follow-On Meetings",
        "monthinwords": "July",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Priya",
        "week": "Week 1",
        "MeetingHash": "Hold/Uncategorized",
        "monthinwords": "May",
        "count": 2
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Priya",
        "week": "Week 2",
        "MeetingHash": "1st Presentation / Meeting",
        "monthinwords": "Jun",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Priya",
        "week": "Week 1",
        "MeetingHash": "Follow-On Meetings",
        "monthinwords": "Jun",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Priya",
        "week": "Week 2",
        "MeetingHash": "1st Presentation / Meeting",
        "monthinwords": "May",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Priya",
        "week": "Week 1",
        "MeetingHash": "Follow-On Meetings",
        "monthinwords": "July",
        "count": 1
    }
];

const item = {}
data.forEach(obj => {
          const key =`${obj.MeetingHash}_${obj.UserName}_${obj.monthinwords}`;
         
              if(!item[key]) { 
                  item[key] = {
                    "Week 1": 0,
                     "Week 2": 0,
                      "Week 3": 0,
                       "Week 4": 0,
                  }
                }
      
              item[key]["UserName"] = obj.UserName
              item[key]["MeetingHash"] = obj.MeetingHash
              item[key]["month"] =  obj.monthinwords
              item[key][obj.week] = obj.count

            }
);
const temp1 = []
Object.keys(item).forEach(record => {
    temp1.push(item[record])
})
//console.log(temp)
temp2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( temp1, ["UserName","MeetingHash","month","Week 1","Week 2","Week 3","Week 4"] ));
order = { '1st Presentation / Meeting': 1, 'Follow-On Meetings': 2, 'Hold/Uncategorized': 3 };
temp=temp2.sort((a, b) => a.UserName.localeCompare(b.UserName)||
    order[a.MeetingHash] - order[b.MeetingHash]);
// Gather the headers we'll have in the end table
const stages = temp.reduce((res, row) => {
  if (!res.includes(row.week)) res.push(row.week);
  return res;
}, []); 
//console.log(stages);

const obj = temp.reduce((res, row) => {
  if (!res[row.MeetingHash]) {
    res[row.MeetingHash] = Object.fromEntries([ ['Geo', row.meetingHash], ...stages.map(s => [s, 0]) ]);
  }
  res[row.MeetingHash][row.week] += row.count;
  res[row.MeetingHash].Total += row.count;
  return res;
}, {}); 
 //console.log(obj);
const summary = Object.values(obj); 
 //console.log(summary);

$('thead').append(
  Object.keys(temp[0]).map(x => $('<td>').text(x))
);
$('tbody').append(
  temp.map(row => $('<tr>').append(
     Object.values(row).map(x => $('<td>').text(x))
  ))
);
```

```css
table{border-collapse:collapse}td{border:1px solid #000;padding:.5em}.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table> <thead> </thead> <tbody> </tbody></table>
```

Comment: So what is stopping you? What is the expected output for given input?

Comment: I can arrange one by one not as desired

Comment: Please explain what to click to sum and how the sum should look in your table. It does not have any room for sums